# Populating Javascript-Object keys/values in loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I want to do something like this:

```
let obj = [];

for(let i=0;i<4;i++) {

// doing some stuff here ...
// and then, finally:

obj[i].words = wordsOfSentence;
}
```

However this gives me an error.

> Cannot set property 'words' of undefined

For now, I solved it like this:

```
let obj = [{}, {}, {}, {}];

for(let i=0;i<4;i++) {

// doing some stuff here ...
// and then, finally:

obj[i].words = wordsOfSentence;
}
```

...but this means I have to always push an empty object into the array beforehand? Whats the standard / an elegant solution here?

Comment: Where does the 4 come from? Maybe share some more code to get a better answer

Comment: oh, sorry about that. it's just hard coded for now, based on another array; in the future it will just use that arrays `.length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have to create a blank JSON object, before store any key-value pair and then you will push a JSON object in array.

```
let objects = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    objects[i] = {};
    objects[i].words = 'wordsOfSentence';  
    objects.push(objects[i]);  

}

console.log(objects);
```

Comment: I did't understand you question can you please explain in little bit brief.

Comment: i just mentioned the term *JSON*. this is only **stringified** data, but not an array or object.

Answer (score 0):

Create the object and then add it to the array:

```
let obj = [];

for(let i=0;i<4;i++) {

// doing some stuff here ...
// and then, finally:
const newObj = { words: wordsOfSentence }
obj[i] = newObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if statement

```
if( obj[i] ){
  obj[i].words = wordsOfSentence;
}
```

Or you can assign a default value before accessing

```
obj[i] = obj[i] || {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply push a new object in each iteration.

```js
let objects = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    objects.push({words: wordsOfSentence});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let _obj = {};
_obj.words = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {    
    _obj.words.push('WordsOfSentense');
}
console.log(_obj);
```

This should help.